# Can I extract conditions from 'if' statements from LLVM IR?

Tags: llvm

There is a way to extract information about call instruction (Using CallInst class of LLVM). Is there any way I can extract metadata of an 'if' instruction also? Like the variable name, operator, or literal?

Answer (score 0):

Such operations can be performed by writing an [LLVM Pass](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html). Essentially, you should implement a `runOnFunction()` that can intercept Instructions during the process. The following pass reads the compare predicate from branch instructions.

```
namespace {
  struct PredicateNamePass: public FunctionPass {
    static char ID; // Pass identification, replacement for typeid
    PredicateNamePass() : FunctionPass(ID) {}
    bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override {
      for (Instruction& I : inst_range(F) ) {
        if (I.isTerminator()) {
          if ( strcmp(I.getOperand(0)->getName().str().c_str(), "cmp") == 0 )
              if ( CmpInst *cp = dyn_cast<CmpInst>(I.getPrevNode()) )
                  errs() << cp->getPredicate() << '\n';
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
  };
}
```

Example program:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int a = 10;
  if( argc == 3)
      a = 11;
  else
      a++;
  return 0;
}
```

command:

```
> opt -load ../build.llvm/lib/LLVMPredicateNamePass.so \ 
  -PredicateNamePass < example.bc > /dev/null
```

output:

```
> 32
```

Comment: I want all metadata attached with an `if` instruction. No metadata is being printed. My code:
`if (ICmpInst* iCmpInst = dyn_cast<ICmpInst>(&*i)) {
 errs() << iCmpInst->getOpcodeName() << '\t';
 errs() << iCmpInst->getPredicate() << '\t';
 SmallVector<std::pair<unsigned, MDNode*>, 8> MDs;
 iCmpInst->getAllMetadata(MDs);
 SmallVector<StringRef, 8> Names;
  F.getContext().getMDKindNames(Names);
  for(SmallVector<std::pair<unsigned, MDNode*>, 8>::iterator II = MDs.begin(), EE = MDs.end(); II !=EE; ++II) {
  errs() << "name: " << Names[II->first] << "\n";
  }
}`

Comment: @DhritiKhanna: Did you try compiling using the -g flag in clang?

Comment: I tried just now. It gives this warning `warning: ignoring debug info with an invalid version (1) in file.bc` and prints nothing.

Comment: @Dhriti Khanna : How are you compiling? Can you type in your clang command?

Comment: `clang-3.5 -g -c -emit-llvm -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include/openmpi -pthread file.c -o file.bc`

I am compiling a simple MPI program.

Comment: Is this correct: `F.getContext().getMDKindNames(Names); `? `F` is a function.

Comment: @DhritiKhanna Oops, my computer wasn't working. Do it like this
`SmallVector<StringRef, 8> names;
Module* md = F.getParent();
md->getMDKindNames(names);
for( auto &X : names)
  errs() << X << '\n';`